# Dimensional shipping UPS Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, ups

I'm using UPS shipping in our Magento website. Currently, I'm able to retrieve shipping charges and no:of boxes required to ship the product using the weight of the products in the order.
However, I would like to introduce the concept of dimensional weight shipping by passing the product dimensions (length,width,height) to arrive shipping charges and no: boxes required to ship the product in the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mageno does not support dimension for UPS but you can simply add you data to UPS api request
it should be something like this

```
      <Dimensions>
          <UnitOfMeasurement>
             <Code>{$unit}</Code>
          </UnitOfMeasurement>
          <Length>{$length}</Length>
          <Width>{$with}</Width>
          <Height>{$height}</Height>
      </Dimensions>
```

find UPS carrier module and add above line. i think you can find it near line 800
i'm trying to publish a module for this problem.